# Incrementally grepping a single text file with a configurable GUI

Tags: search, gui

I have a fairly large text file (~1000 lines, Markdown format) that I would like to quickly grep for lines that include or exclude certain words. This is a large file, so I need the feedback of incremental search.

The matching does not depend on the order of the words, so `word1 word2` should match a line containing `word2 word1`.

I have been using commands like `grep 'word1|word2' file.txt | grep -v word3`, but this quickly becomes tiresome since the words tend to be different each time. This is why I want a GUI, not command line input.

The GUI must hide non-matching lines, not jumping to matching ones as in a normal text editor. Somethings like vim's [global command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862966/hide-all-notmatching-lines-in-vim) is close, but it's too cumbersome for entering long patterns and doesn't have the quick feedback of incremental search.

A desktop file indexer like [recoll](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/) is also close, but it is designed for multiple files and does not have incremental search.

The GUI should be very fast to change which ones I'm including or excluding. It should also be possible to retain and recall previous patterns.

Finally, the GUI must run on Linux.

Comment: Emacs can be made to do anything. Still, hard to compete with grep in terms of speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get BareGrep working under wine:

http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baregrep-2.00/index.php